# Does Orthodox Judaism have a generally held position on American politics?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, chutz-laaretz, politics-government, orthodox

The [Pew Research Study](http://www.pewforum.org/2013/10/01/chapter-6-social-and-political-views/) on Jewish Americans says in part:

> On these measures (partisanship and ideology), the only other U.S. religious groups that are as conservative and Republican as Orthodox Jews are white evangelical Protestants and Mormons.

With ultra-Orthodox more strongly identified that way than Modern Orthodox. For non-Orthodox Jews (and especially if you remove Conservative from the mix):

> Jews by religion are more than twice as likely as members of most other religious traditions to describe themselves as politically liberal. And black Protestants are the only religious group with a larger share than Jews by religion that identifies with or leans toward the Democratic Party.

(For those outside of America, if you view politics as a two dimensional line, these two positions are on right and left side of the line, respectively).

What about Orthodox Jewish beliefs cause people with an otherwise similar cultural and ancestral background and experience in America to reach different political conclusions than their compatriots who do not have this religious belief? Is there something specific about the beliefs of Orthodox Judaism that is interpreted as requiring association with one side of the political spectrum over the other, or is this correlation unrelated to religious belief and practice?

Note that for purposes of this survey, self-identification was all that was used. If someone identified themselves as Orthodox and as Republican, it was reported as such. So an objective definition of Republican isn't necessary to answer this question, but rather something which correlates the impression among Orthodox adherents about what political groups they are more affiliated with.

Possible objective sources of answers:

1. Clear statements from influential Rabbis, Rabbinic Organizations or lay leadership in the Orthodox world which support such political leanings.
2. A social scientists study on what may create that correlation.
3. Personal experience with broad ranges of Orthodox Jews and finding a common theme in what they express about their political leanings.
4. Something I didn't think of.

Comment: @close-voters Why is this off-topic or opinion based?  On topic: It asks about Jewish values that would create a certain affiliation, not about Jews.  Not opinion-based: It asks about specific beliefs of Orthodox Judaism, which I assume could be sourced and objective.

Comment: I think this is a great question, and was actually going to ask it (with slight variation) myself.

Comment: @YEZ, thanks, I was just writing a comment to that effect as well, you beat me to it.

Comment: This question is a better fit for http://politics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Jake, Looking at what is [on topic](http://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) over there, it seems not. You could maybe ask who Jews support politically. But what is on topic there stops where this question starts (if I understand their rules correctly).

Comment: @Jake politics SE does not discuss what the views of Judaism are.  It may discuss what Jews do, and their voting habits.  But this question isn't asking for that.  It is asking for the Jewish value that leads to such a thing.

Comment: @Jake regarding your comment on Sabbahillel's now deleted answer: sourced answers may be higher quality, but answers which provide their own justification are definitely accepted.  Saying "I don't think so" without backing yourself up is worthless, but providing logical support is fine.  Consider the top 3, highly upvoted, answers to [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26908/how-do-i-get-myself-to-yearn-for-moshiach-if-im-comfortable-in-the-diaspora) question.

Comment: @sabbahillel and all: Conversation on YEZ's last comment continues [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17398712#17398712). Please don't continue it here.

Comment: @YEZ I don't see how this is different from [comparative religion questions](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/828/2). We are asked to compare Judaism with another named but not-here-defined idealogy and interest group. There's no more reason (well, except for said Pew report, I guess :^/) to expect users here to be experts on conservatism or Republican politics than there is to expect them to be experts on Christianity.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I think you have a valid point - does the edit help?

Comment: Okay, you convinced me.  So I answered the question.

Comment: @YEZ, Would links to the WP article about Christianity make a comparative religion quesiton on-topic? (Honest quesiton)

Comment: @IsaacMoses, Questions about how Judaism regards X about Christianity are on topic. How is this different? It is asking what about Jewish beliefs cause adherents to have a different political disposition than those who don't.

Comment: @IsaacMoses No.  But if the WP article had a 1 line summary of what the philosophy is, along with a [bullet list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservatism_in_the_United_States#Kirk.27s_principles_of_conservatism) of their central beliefs which were relevant to the question, then I would reconsider.

Comment: @Yishai only if "X about Christianity" is well defined enough that it doesn't require me to bring my own knowledge about it. (that's what I tried to accomplish with the WP links)

Comment: @YEZ, I don't think that standard is particularly held to. This [question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33467/among-the-gentiles-why-job-and-bilaam-were-recognized-as-prophets-whereas-muham) tells me nothing about Mohamed (other than a questionable assertion). [This question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89/is-christianity-avodah-zara) explains nothing about Christianity, just throws out terms, etc. The only distinction I see is that you expect Jewish sources to directly address those two points, whereas if anything addresses this it would be recent and thinner.

Comment: @Yishai I'm not sure if you need to know more about Mohamed.  It may be a question that would receive better answers with more info, but I could ask "Bob claims to be a prophet.  Why isn't he recognized by Judaism as one?" and I think it would be answerable.  The Christianity example, OTOH, is a good קשיא.

Comment: I tend to agree with @IsaacMoses and given that there are already 3 other close votes (so I'm not overly asserting my mod-powers), I'm putting this on hold for now. I think the above discussion should be moved to a [meta] post where others can voice there positions in an organized fashion.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2143/the-scope-of-comparative-religion

Answer (score 1):

> In demographic terms, Hasidic Jews are more similar to some highly religious Christian groups than liberal Jews,” Comenetz said. “They may also sympathize more with the Republicans than the Democrats on values questions. So, one outcome may be a change in the way Jews vote.”

Quote is from [here](http://news.ufl.edu/archive/2006/11/as-hasidic-population-grows-jewish-politics-may-shift-right.html)

Christianity gets most of its morality from Judaism, and this is a fact that many Christians will happily admit.  In the USA, basic questions of morality did not divide the two major political parties, until the latter part of the 20th century.

A Jew who desires to keep the laws of liberal progressivism, will of course gravitate to politicians that promise to promote the liberal progressive agenda.

However, a Jew who desires to keep the laws of Hashem, will identify with politicians who follow a very similar set of morals.

There are a few Orthodox Jews who have held prominent positions within the Democratic Party.  Joe Liberman was a US Senator for decades, although today's Democratic Party has shifted tremendously to the progressive left in the decades since Senator Liberman first entered politics.

The current US Treasury Secretary is also an Orthodox Jew, and a progressive liberal, but this requires a great deal of [Cognitive Dissonance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance).  Essentially, this ideological position requires one to say to oneself "I personally believe that X is a sin, but society is better off if we spend lots of tax money promoting X, and making sure more X happens all over the country"

There are several issues on which Orthodox Jews and Conservative Republicans have found increasing common ground, such as:

- School Vouchers (yeshiva tuition would be partially covered by funds already allotted for your children's public school education)
- Religious Freedom (we don't want the government telling us how to shecht, how to do brit milah, or what we have to teach our children)
- Support for Israel (even Satmar doesn't want Hamas or Hezbollah to kill all the Jews in Israel).

Conversely, while Orthodox Jews may be less concerned with allowing gentiles to have abortions, or allowing two men to get a piece of paper calling them 'married', we certainly understand *why* the Conservative Christian world fights actively against these things.  The basis for their opposition is our Torah, as they understand it.

While the U.S. Jewish population is [larger than previously estimated](http://ejewishphilanthropy.com/u-s-jewish-population-substantially-larger-than-previously-estimated/) , nearly all of the gain in population is from Orthodox Jews.  Very few non-Orthodox Jews have more than two children, and many don't have kids at all, so all growth in our demographic for the foreseeable future will come from shomrei torah u'mitzvot.

Comment: Are you sure that we [aren't concerned with allowing two men to get a piece of paper calling them 'married'](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8477/what-is-the-halachic-source-for-objection-to-gay-civil-marriage)?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89/is-christianity-avodah-zara

Comment: @YEZ I'm sure.  I'm not stating my political opinion on the issue, but it's certainly not something that deeply affects the frum velt, like laws against brit milah, or school vouchers, do.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin well, now that we're apparently allowing Jewish political questions, that should be its own question.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin No more than the "strings" already attached to yeshiva schools in the US, which are required to teach a certain amount of limud chol.

Comment: As @ShmuelBrin is alluding to, what this question is missing is a clear explanation of why, culturally, certain "laws of Hashem" factor more strongly in many Orthodox Jews' choice of political affinity than others. It's easy enough to set up, in the course of discussion, "liberal progressivism" as obviously in basic opposition to "laws of Hashem," but, depending on what, precisely, those two labels mean, they may overlap a great deal. I believe it is true that many Orthodox Jews do make the same assumption of these labels' opposition, but this answer doesn't make it clear why.

Comment: Summary: Objectively, Orthodox Jews are Repulican because to be Democratic and Orthodox means you are crazy. (I'm just waiting for another answer to come along and say the exact opposite.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't say crazy.  Cognitive Dissonance is something we all do to some degree.  Yaakov Lew isn't crazy, he's a brilliant man, a fine yid, and dead wrong on proper size and role of government.  That's all.

Comment: @Jake And all of us are crazy to some degree. What you didn't account for is someone being Liberal without cognitive dissonance because you apparently can't even see such an option.

Comment: We don't want government telling us how to Shecht, how to do Bris Milah, and whom we can get married to. I would hate if the government told me who I could married to if my religion told me otherwise. That's religious freedom. Most conservatives don't actually believe in it. They just believe in freedom to practice Christianity. You literally wrote in the same post that they support religious freedom and support implementing their scripture as law. Is that a joke? Talk about cognitive dissonance...